# How do i get 3D itens to stay static in the scene?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe, ar.js

I'm trying to develop a web system which uses the smartphone's camera to AR experience.

I would like to let 3D objects static in the scene, but in the tests, the objects keep moving and flicking.

To be more specific, my objects are pipes and they need to be static, so the person can see where they are located "through" the walls.

Here's the sample of the code.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Entity-Component - Registry</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Entity-Component - Registry">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
  </head>

 <body style="margin: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
   <a-scene embedded arjs>
     <a-assets>
       <a-asset-item id="roomOBJ" src="./models/SALA_TATO_2.obj"></a-asset-item>
       <a-asset-item id="roomMLT" src="./models/SALA_TATO_2.mtl"></a-asset-item>
     </a-assets>
     <a-marker preset="hiro">
       <a-entity static-body obj-model="obj: #roomOBJ; mtl: #roomMLT" position="-7 0 -3" rotation="0 0 0"></a-entity>
     </a-marker>
     <a-entity camera look-controls position="0 1.6 -3" rotation="0 50 0"></a-entity>
     </a-scene>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: It's around moving even when the hiro marker is detected?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use the hiro marker and unfortunately it wasn't working out. Now i'm trying to use static positions in order to 'anchor' the objects in the scene, but when i'm walking around, eventualy the 3D models gets repositioned.